# Can child bot exit the whole/parent's conversation?

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I have several bots: 1 for each product. And then 1 common child bot for common intents. The child bot does a context.Done() for each intent so that it returns the context back to the parent.

The child bot has an "Exit" intent. And I want that intent to exit both child and parent.

I was thinking, if I can get the message passed through the child's context.Done("EXITED") then I can work with that. But I don't know how to do that either.

Comment: By "I have several bots", do you mean you have base-multi dialogs in your bot application? And what do you mean by "I want that intent to exit both child and parent.", do you want to clear the whole dialog stack?

Comment: I created several apps in Luis.ai: Product1, Product2..., CommonLuis. From RootDialog I show a Form asking which Product the customer is interested with. Then I use that product specific luis bot. For product-generic stuff, I have CommonLuis. Then one of those product-generic stuff is to Exit the whole conversation.

So from child (CommonLuis), when it detects "ExitIntent", I do context.UserData.Clear() and basically want to call context.Done() in parent. So I go back to the RootDialog.

Comment: When you add a new Dialog to the stack ore you using either context.forward() or context.call()?  Both of these have a "resume after" method in which you should be able to call another context.done to move up in the dialog stack again.  Also, this [Repo](https://github.com/EricDahlvang/EndConversationTest) may help you too.

Comment: @JasonSowers I use context.Forward(). How will ResumeAfter method know what the Luis-Child-Dialog's intent was? So that I can assume that it entered ExitIntent in child dialog?

Comment: Take a look at [scorables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-global-handlers) This might be a better solution for you now that I think about it.   That way you will not need to handle the "exit" within a Luis Dialog, it will be handled globally instead.  To answer your question, you could put a key in `Context.ConversationData` or `Context.UserData` databags and check for that key inside your resume after method.

Comment: @JasonSowers I'm sorry it took a while but I finally understood what you meant! Thanks!

Comment: I will definitely check that out! Thanks again! @JasonSowers